# How do I convert a php date string from Y/m/d to Y-m-d

Tags: php

I have a string that's currently `16/06/2012` and I'd like to convert it into `2012-06-16`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Was it really too hard to look at one of the thousands of identical questions in the "related" box that popped up when you typed in the question title? Or to Google `convert php date string`?

Comment: Interesting that Pekka just commented. Here is a reference to the answer Pekka gave. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date_array = explode("/","16/06/2012");

$new_date = $date_array[2]."-".$date_array[1]."-".$date_array[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime(implode("/", array_reverse(explode("/", "16/06/2012")))))
```

Comment: At that point, why even use `date()` and `strtotime()`? When you `implode()`, just use "-" instead of "/" and you're done.